# android: Light up screen (and unlock) while receiving sms

Tags: android

I want to light up screen while receiving sms in my app. What should I do? And is it possible to unlock screen too?
Thanks!

Comment: I just want to light up phone to inform user, if possible. All other things works fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PowerManager to wake up the Screen

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)   getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
        wakeLock.acquire();
```

and add a Permission in Manifest

```
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```